# Cakephp strange image src link

Tags: cakephp

I have a backend and a frontend.
In the frontend all is right. The image link is correct and the image is displayed.

```
/img/imgProducts/Coda_VolpeAmineo%20Coda%20di%20Volpe%20IGP%206%20bottiglie%20?1367589931
```

In the backend, same code, I have a blank image.

```
/img/imgProducts/Coda_VolpeAmineo%20Coda%20di%20Volpe%20IGP%206%20bottiglie%20
```

Why in the frontend I see that random number? Without that the image is blank. Who is putting that number?

The code is

```
 echo ($html->image(($this->data['Product']['imagelink']),array('title'=>$this->data['Product']['name'],'width'=>80 )));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Asset timestamping

The random number at the end of the URL is a timestamp, used to prevent caching older versions of the image by webbrowsers.

By default, timestamping assets (images) is disabled, but it may be enabled during development (I.e. when 'debug' is enabled), but can also be *forced* by setting the `Asset.timestamp` configuration inside `app/Config/core.php` to 'force'

Look for `Configure::write('Asset.timestamp', true);` in your app. See this line inside the core.php configuration file:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/core.php#L212

### important

If you're seeing timestamps in your URLs, this may be caused by debug being enabled inside `app/Config/core.php`. Running a live website with debug enabled is really discouraged. Not only will this make your website slow (as server-side caching is disabled), **it will also output error-messages inside the browser, which may be a security risk in some cases!**

Comment: I knew about debug mode, but I didn't know about the Asset.timestamp.

Comment: It's not a very well-known feature, but handy during development to prevent caching. Anyway, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

That's a [URL encoded image link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).. You probably have spaces and other characters in the filename of your image.